# Making user friendly basic calculator java

Tags: java

I'm almost done with my program, but I need to make my code more user friendly.

How can I make it only ask to the user to enter the operation and just one digit when it comes to logs, cos, sin, tan, and square root? So far it asks the user to enter two digits and the operation, the first digit never matter though.

```
package calculator2;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Addition");
        System.out.println("Subtraction");
        System.out.println("Division");
        System.out.println("Multiplication");
        System.out.println("Natural Log");
        System.out.println("Exponent");
        System.out.println("cos");
        System.out.println("sin");
        System.out.println("tan");
        System.out.println("root");
        System.out.println("pactorial");
        System.out.println("compitation");
        System.out.println("-------------------------");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput ;

       do{
           calculator();
           System.out.println("Would you like to do another calculation. Enter Y for yes or N for no");
            userInput = scan.nextLine();
       }while (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
        System.out.println("Goodbye");

        }

    public static void calculator(){

        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a calculation. With a space in between digit and opertation. ");
        System.out.println("Like 1 + 1 . For log, first press 0, then operator 'log' follow by digit you wish to calculate.");

        double value1 = user.nextDouble();
        String op = user.next();
        double value2 = user.nextDouble();

         if (op.equals("+")){
             Addition(value1,value2);

         }if (op.equals("-")){
             Subtraction(value1,value2);

         }if(op.equals("/")){
             Division(value1,value2);

         }if(op.equals("*")){
             Multiplication(value1,value2);

         }if(op.equals("^")){
             Exponent(value1,value2);

         }if(op.equals("log")){
             NaturalLog(value1);

         }if(op.equals("cos")){
             cos(value2);

         }if(op.equals("sin")){
             sin(value2);
         }if(op.equals("tan")){
             tan(value2);

         }if(op.equals("root")){
             root(value2);
         }if(op.equals("patory")){
             patory(value1, value2);
         }if(op.equals("comb")){
             comb(value1 , value2);
         }else{
         }
    }
    public static void Addition (double value1, double value2){
        double Sum= value1 + value2;
        System.out.println(Sum);
    }
    public static void Subtraction (double value1 , double value2){
        double diff = value1 - value2;
        System.out.println(diff);
    }
    public static void Division(double value1 , double value2){
        double div = value1 / value2;
        System.out.println(div);
    }
    public static void Multiplication(double value1, double value2){
       double mult =  value1 * value2;
        System.out.println(mult);
    }
    public static void Exponent(double value1 , double value2){
        double exp =  Math.pow(value1, value2);
        System.out.println(exp);
    }
    public static void NaturalLog(double value2){
        double logs = Math.log(value2);
        System.out.println(logs);
    }
      public static void cos(double value2){
          double cas = Math.cos(value2);
          System.out.println(cas);
      }
      public static void sin(double value2){
          double sins = Math.sin(value2);
          System.out.println(sins);

      }
      public static void tan(double value2){
          double tans = Math.tan(value2);
          System.out.println(tans);
      }
     public static void root(double value2){
         double sqroot = Math.sqrt(value2);
         System.out.println(sqroot);

     } 
     public static void patory(double value1 , double value2){
         double denominator =1;
         double numarator = 1;
         for(double i = value1; i>=1; i--){
             numarator *= i;

         }
         for(double j = value1 - value2; j>= 1; j--){
             denominator *= j;
         }
         System.out.println(numarator/denominator);

     }
     public static void comb( double value1, double value2){
         double denominator1 = 1;
         double denominator2 = 1;
         double numarator = 1;

         for(double i =value1; i >=1; i--){
             numarator *= i;

         }
         for( double j = value2; j>=1; j--){
             denominator1 *= j;
         }
         for(double j = value1 - value2; j>=1; j--){
             denominator2 *= j;

         }
         System.out.println(numarator/(denominator1*denominator2));
     }
}
```

Comment: i dont know why i am being down voted. is it that the question is dumb or what. at least explain.

Comment: It's probably a combination of the fact that your formatting was all messed up and the fact that the majority of your code is irrelevant to the problem. See [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you're doing `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);` twice which is unnecessary. Further, calling `.next()` not inside a try/catch block might crash your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple conditional needs to be added.

```
if(function ==log||function == sin||etc.) 
//Something like this in conditional
{
 value2 = user.nextDouble(); 
 //get user input only once for special cases that satisfy conditional
}
else
{
  value1 = user.nextDouble(); //get user input normally.
  String op = user.next();
  value2 = user.nextDouble();
}
```

**LOGIC**
If the function is not one of those special functions then ask for 2 numbers and get the operation... Else if the conditional is satisfied as the user wants the sin tangent etc... then only scan for one number .

Comment: @adonis Here is a solution. Just change the conditional to the operations that only need one input

Answer (score 0):

You should split your code to support two cases: unary-functions (like root/log/cos/etc) and bi-functions (like: +-/*).

So I would modify the code of `calculator()` to be something like:

```
public static void calculator() {

    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a calculation. With a space in between digit and opertation. ");
    System.out.println("Like 1 + 1 . For log, first press 0, then operator 'log' follow by digit you wish to calculate.");

    String command = user.nextLine();
    String[] ops = command.split("\\s+");
    if (ops.length == 2) {
        biFunction(ops);
    } else {
        unaryFunction(ops);
    }
}
```

and implement `biFunction(ops)` and `unaryFunction(ops)` respectively.

Comment: sorry whats is biFunction and unaryFunction, im new to coding

Comment: read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation)